# Deserializing XML from XStream in Scala without using asInstanceOf?

Tags: scala, xstream

I'm using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) in my Scala app with the following thin wrapper:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream._

object SXStream {
  private val xstream = new XStream

  def fromXML[T](xml: String): T = {
    xstream.fromXML(xml).asInstanceOf[T]
  } 

  def toXML[T](obj: T): String = {
    xstream.toXML(obj)
  } 
}
```

Is this the best I'm going to get, or is there a way around that `asInstanceOf`? It looks like casting is the recommended usage in Java; I'm wondering if Scala provides me some cleaner option.

Comment: I get the error `com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException` when I try to use this, what am I missing?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the `asInstanceOf`, but the advantages are limited -- the code becomes more idiomatic and you can make the `ClassCastException` more specific:

```
def any(xml: String): Any = xml
def fromXML[T: ClassTag](xml: String): T = any(xml) match {
  case a: T => a
  case other => throw new RuntimeException("Invalid type " + other.getClass + " found during marshalling of xml " + xml)
}
```

On the other hand, this is more verbose and probably less efficient than the `asInstanceOf` call.

Comment: `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` should be used instead of `Manifest`. It is deprecated since Scala 2.10.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made that change.

Comment: @yakshaver Since when could you match on a type `T` in pattern matching. Doesn't type erasure completely defeat what you're attempting to do?

Comment: @wheaties, Scala allows to pattern match on generic type if you provide `ClassTag` or `TypeTag`, just as in the example.